# Split a long byte array into numpy array of strings

Tags: python, c, numpy

Usually, when creating an numpy array of strings, we can do something like

```
import numpy as np
np.array(["Hello world!", "good bye world!", "whatever world"])
>>> array(['Hello world!', 'good bye world!', 'whatever world'], dtype='<U15')
```

Now the question is, I am given a long bytearray from a foreign C function like this:

```
b'Hello world!\x00<some rubbish bytes>good bye world!\x00<some rubbish bytes>whatever world\x00<some rubbish bytes>'
```

It is guaranteed that every 32 bytes is a null-terminated string (i.e., there is a `\x00` byte appended to the valid part of the string) and I need to convert this long bytearray to something like this, `array(['Hello world!', 'good bye world!', 'whatever world'], dtype='<U15')`, preferably in-place (i.e., no memory copy).

This is what I do now：

```
for i in range(str_count):
    str_arr[i] = byte_arr[i * 32: (i+1) * 32].split(b'\x00')[0].decode('utf-8')
str_arr_np = np.array(str_arr),
```

It works, but it is kind of awkward and not done in-place (bytes are copied at least once, if not twice). Are there any better approaches?

Comment: can you please give a real example input with the real, expected output? How are we supposed to distinguish "rubbish bytes"?

Comment: As I said, it is guaranteed that every 32 bytes is a null-terminated string. This is how  C handles rubbish bytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string.

Comment: So every 32 bytres there is the *beginning* of some null-terminated string which can potentially take up to 32 bytes (but possibly less)? Again, please just give a real example

Comment: let me give an example in which each null-terminated string is 16 bytes long only, so it wont be too long, the input will be `b'Hello world!\x00\x01\xAA\xBBgood bye world!\x00whatever world\x00\x99'`. So yes, each string is at most 16 bytes long, but it could be shorter, if it is shorter, it will be appended by a `\x00` and the rest of the bytes are rubbish.

Comment: Do you have access to the C side of the transform? It's easy enough to _null-out_ the 32 byte buffer(s) (in C) before filling each with up to 31 characters (plus at least one terminating '\0')...

Comment: hey @Fe2O3 yes I have the control over the C side as well, and yes if needed I can zero the memory out before using it. If so, how can it help?

Comment: I don't know Python or its "numpy" associates... Seems you want to either dispose of "rubbish data" bytes, or compress the valid bytes somehow... Python "methods" may involve a lot of "behind the scenes" operations that you may not need...

Comment: Hey @Fe2O3, based on your hint another user does provide a better approach! In my initial design, as I didnt know how it could help, so I let the memory content as indeterminate. But it can be `memset()`'ed to before use.

Comment: If you've got an answer that works for you, you should "accept" that answer to mark this question as resolved. (I don't see how Python (or numpy) will know how many 32 byte elements there are in the array, but that's something for greater minds than mine to work out :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 it wont, but it assumes that the buffer size is a mulitple of the item size (and will complain if it isn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *can* zero out the data on the C side, then you can use `np.frombuffer` and it will be about as efficient as you can reasonably expect:

So, if you can zero out the data, then this can be read using `numpy.frombuffer` and it will probably be as efficient as you can reasonably expect to get:

```
>>> raw = b'hello world\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Good Bye\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> np.frombuffer(raw, dtype='S16')
array([b'hello world', b'Good Bye'], dtype='|S16')
```

Of course, this gives you a *bytes string*, not unicode string, although, that may be desirable in your case.

Note, the above relies on the built-in behavior of stripping trailing null bytes, if you have garbage afterwards, it won't work:

```
>>> data = b'hello world\x00aaaaGood Bye\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> np.frombuffer(data, dtype='S16')
array([b'hello world\x00aaaa', b'Good Bye'], dtype='|S16')
```

Note, this shouldn't make a copy, notice:

```
>>> arr = np.frombuffer(raw, dtype='S16')
>>> arr
array([b'hello world', b'Good Bye'], dtype='|S16')
>>> arr[0] = b"z"*16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

However, if the destination is not read-only, so say you had a `bytearray` to begin with:

```
>>> raw = bytearray(raw)
>>> arr = np.frombuffer(raw, dtype='S16')
>>> arr[0] = b"z"*16
>>> arr
array([b'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz', b'Good Bye'], dtype='|S16')
>>> raw
bytearray(b'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzGood Bye\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: Let's assume there isnt any rubbish bytes, all unused bytes are `\x00`--is it possible to use something like `np.ctypeslib.as_array(int_ptr, shape=(int_count,))`? The advantage is that we use the memory as it is, not a single copy operation. This works for integers. The tricky part is that, I need to let `numpy` know that each element is 16 bytes long.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind hmmm I hesitate to suggest this, but I believe using the `np.ndarray` constructor directly (which it is not meant to be), `np.ndarray(shape=(2,), buffer=raw, dtype='S16')` would use the underlying buffer without copying it.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind although, actually, `np.frombuffer` is not making a copy of the underlying data, I believe. Indeed, try to assign to the array created from a `bytes` object and it complains that you are trying to write to a read-only destination. If you used a `bytearray` instead, you see the changes in both!

Comment: why dont you suggest this? `Numpy`'s document says it is inadvisable or it may risk leaking memory? In my case, the memory pointed by `byte_arr` is solely prepared by C program to be used by `Numpy`, so it wont become corrupt a while later because other functions modify it.

Comment: actually, np.frombuffer is not making a copy of the underlying data -> oh really, let me try as well

Comment: seems yes, the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) says "This function creates a view into the original object. This should be safe in general, but it may make sense to copy the result when the original object is mutable or untrusted."